# Как добавить несколько типов для поля при создании схемы Avro?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

есть метод для создания схемы Avro:

```
public void schemaCreator(String recordName, EntityModel entityModel){
        SchemaBuilder.FieldAssembler<Schema> fields;
        SchemaBuilder.RecordBuilder<Schema> record = SchemaBuilder.record(recordName);
        fields = record.namespace("Test").fields();
        for (AttributeModel attributeModel : entityModel.getAttributeModels()) {


            fields = fields.name(attributeModel.getName()).type().nullable().stringType()
                    .noDefault();

        }
    }
```

В результате имеем схему:

```
{
 "type":"record",
 "name":"InfoData",
 "namespace":"Test",
 "fields":[
   {
    "name":"Setting",
    "type":["string","null"]
   },
   {
    "name":"Value",
    "type":["string","null"]}]
   }
```

Как добавить несколько типов для поля? 
Например: "type":["string","long","boolean","null"]}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вариант решения, таким образом можно формировать список типов в цикле:

```
public void schemaCreator(String recordName, EntityModel entityModel){
        SchemaBuilder.FieldAssembler<Schema> fields;
        SchemaBuilder.RecordBuilder<Schema> record = SchemaBuilder.record(recordName);
        fields = record.namespace("Test").fields();
        final Schema intType = Schema.create(Schema.Type.INT);
        final Schema booleanType = Schema.create(Schema.Type.BOOLEAN);
        final Schema nullType = Schema.create(Schema.Type.NULL);

        for (AttributeModel attributeModel : entityModel.getAttributeModels()) {
            Schema unionSchema = Schema.createUnion(Arrays.asList(nullType, intType, booleanType));
            fields.name(attributeModel.getName()).type(unionSchema).noDefault();
        }
    }
```